# IE 11 crashes when using GPU rendering - large MVC page with bootstrap and datatables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, datatables

I've got a large mvc 5 bootstrap web page that's repeatedly causing IE to crash.  The page has a large number of bootstrap accordions with jquery datatables in.  The page loads fine but if you scroll too fast then a small white rectangle appears in the upper left side of the page and IE stops responding.

The page is fine with a much reduced amount of data, it's fine in chrome and its fine if you tick the "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering" option in IE.

At the moment my solution is to display a warning on the page to the users that they need to tick that box if I've got more than 100 rows of data but especially as that option requires a restart of IE it's not ideal.

How can I go about fixing this, is it something anyone else has experienced?

Comment: have you check your IE console..may be some error would be their because browser has nothing to do with length of page..

Comment: @stylishCoder hmm, no errors but I seem to be leaking memory and am doing a paint hundreds of times a second, that's given me a new avenue to explore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, fixed but I'm not sure it's applicable for anyone else.  I was using a old version of datatables (1.10.7)  So I updated to the latest and it stopped happening but the memory usage still built up whilst the page was just sitting there.  I removed the flash buttons and changed them to the html5 buttons and everything was much much better.